# Problema con json_encode php y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estoy usando `CodeIgniter` donde tengo un controlador que retorna un array en formato json, y lo quiero recibir desde jquery ajax,pero me sale este error:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined function json_encode()
```

Resulta también que la versión de php que tengo en el servidor es algo antigua, creo es 5.2 y quizás por eso no funciona.

```
public function Datos(){
    $nrofi = $this->input->post('nrofi');
    $data['datos'] = $this->Mimodel->getDatos($nrofi);
    echo json_encode($data);
}


var ficha = xx;
    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: "<?php echo base_url('index.php/MiController/Datos')?>",
                        data: {nrofi: ficha},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(data){
                            var d = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));
                            console.log(d);

                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
```

ese es mi código, en caso de que no pueda usar json, como se puede recuperar el array del controlador desde ajax??

Comment: Debes habilitar la función JSON, te dejo aquí una solución => https://stackoverflow.com/q/7318191/6817375

Comment: ¿Será que tienes una versión de PHP anterior a la 5.2? [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) existe desde **(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PECL json >= 1.2.0, PHP 7)**

Comment: Puedes instalar una extensión del php json_encode en caso de que tu version de php no sea la 5.2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370968/how-can-i-decode-json-in-php-5-1